# Retrofit call within Stream

Tags: android, rx-java, observable, retrofit2, rx-java2

I have an edit text which allows a user to input a username and once the username is input the value is sent to the db to check whether the username already exists,if not then further operations are allowed else an error is displayed.

As of now this is my current code.

```
usernameObservable
            .skip(2)
            .debounce(800, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .subscribe(username -> {
                Observable<Boolean> observable = apiService.isAvailable(username);
                observable.observeOn(Schedulers.io())
                        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                        .subscribe(aBoolean -> {

                        }, throwable -> {

                        });
            });
```

For now the network request is being made at the end but is it possible to make the request before and once i receive data i perform some other operations on the stream.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for `flatMap` operator. It allows you to transform an event into another observable, which will forward emissions to the original stream. You error notification will be forwarded as well.

```
usernameObservable
        .skip(2)
        .debounce(800, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
        .flatMap(username -> apiService.isAvailable(username))
        .subscribe(isAvailableResult -> {
            // react here
        }, throwable -> {
            // show an error here
        });
```

Comment: Is it possible to add other operators after the flatMap and before the subscribe? For example maybe a filter , if so then will the data i receive from the api call be processed or is my original observable being operated on?

Comment: Of course it is possible :-) That's the beauty of Rx .. Once you apply flatMap operator, every item that comes to it is transformed into an observable. All events that are emitted by these observables which you defined in flatMap will be routed back to the original stream. So after flatMap, you work with results of the API endpoint which corresponds to your method call apiService.isAvailable(). You can do what ever you want with them, it is a regular stream.

Comment: However, I see where I might have confused you. I didn't rename the argument in subscribe method.. Of course its not the username anymore, but rather the result of isAvailable() endpoint. I'll edit my answer

Comment: Amazing, just one last question , after the flat map, is it possible to have the username as well as the result of the api endpoint to work with?

Comment: Yes it is :-) .. As it is common to Rx streams, desired behavior can be achieved with multiple different approaches .. One that comes to mind is to simply map the result of isAvailable() endpoint to a Pair object with the corresponding username like this: `apiService.isAvailable(username).map(result -> Pair.create(username, result))` .. This way, the argument in subscribe method will be a Pair with both the result and the username..

Comment: Thank you so much , you've been amazing.